# arrays of object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if i can get the object property using array. I am getting 'undefine' value for this.label[i].xOffset. Any suggestions?

```
function label() {
    var lbl = this;
    lbl.rText;
    lbl.precision =1;
    lbl.prefix = '';
    lbl.suffix = '';
    lbl.xOffset = this.width/2;
    lbl.yOffset = this.height*82/100    
}
this.NoOfneedles=2;
if (this.NoOfneedles > 1) {
    this.label = [];
    for (i=0;i<this.NoOfneedles;i++) {
        this.label[i]=new label();
        alert("label xOffset:"+this.label[i]+this.label[i].xOffset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `label` object has no `width` and `height` properties and already others said you that but if you just define `width` and `height` inside your constructor then it could be written as follows

```
function Label() {
   var lbl = this;
   lbl.width=window.outerWidth;
   lbl.height=window.outerHeight;
   lbl.precision =1;
   lbl.prefix = '';
   lbl.suffix = '';
   lbl.xOffset = lbl.width/2;
   lbl.yOffset = lbl.height*82/100    
}

this.NoOfneedles=2;
if (this.NoOfneedles > 1){
    this.label = [];
    for (i=0;i<this.NoOfneedles;i++){
        this.label[i]=new Label();
        alert ("label xOffset:"+this.label[i].xOffset);
    }
}
```

Remember this refers to current object and you are using `this.width/2;` inside your constructor so `this=Label` and I've changed the `label` to `Label` and outside the constructor/in global scope `this` refers to default global object `window` and in the global scope `this.someVar` and `someVar` is same because `window` is the default global object and by default we don't need to use it so we can use `document.getElementbyId` instrad of `window.document.getElementbyId`.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a problem in you `label` function:

```
lbl.xOffset = this.width/2;
```

Here, `this.width` is `undefined`, because `this` refers to the object you've create with `new label()`. But then, the `xOffset` property of the object would equal to `NaN`. And this line:

```
lbl.rText;
```

does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the prob:

In your constructor function label() you are setting xOffset and yOffset to 'this' width and 'this' height, but 'this' doesn't have width/height properties so they are undefined.